# Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I am new to C#.
What I wanted to do is to increase the lvl everytime my opponent's life turns to 0
I also want to make the maximum lvl up to 5.

```
public int displayMenu()
{
    int pLvl = 1;
    if (opponent.strength == 0)
    {
       (pLvl++);
       a.Write("You are on level: {0}", pLvl);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses around `pLvl++;`

But you're using a local variable. So everytime this method will be called the value will be set back to it's initial value `1`. You could use a field instead.

The parantheses are usually used for [casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx) or to wrap conditional expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use prefix increment shortand:

```
public int displayMenu()
{
    int pLvl = 1;
    if (opponent.strength == 0)
    {
        a.Write("You are on level: {0}", ++pLvl);
    }     
}
```

It will increase `pLvl` by one, and then output your message with incremented value.
Note that after method is executed, `pLvl` value is lost, since it is a local variable. Perhaps, it is not what you actually want.

Comment: Cool, the Error was gone. So how do I make it permanent and make it increment? Thanks.